# Applying the same conditions to 2 different arguments in a function

Tags: javascript

The aim is to call a function with 2 parameters and apply the same conditions to both parameters, Here the conditions:
If `(num1 <= 10)` it is applied a charge of 1
If `(num1 > 10)` it is applied a charge of 2
and also:
If `(num2 <= 10)` it is applied a charge of 1
If `(num2 > 10)` it is applied a charge of 2

Unfortunately it returns only the first argument and does not return `default` if a string is entered as argument. Why? Please help.

```js
function addWithSurcharge(num1, num2) {
  const charge1 = 1
  const charge2 = 2
  switch (true) {
    case (num1 <= 10):
    return num1 + charge1
    case (num1 > 10):
    return num1 + charge2
    case (num2 <= 10):
    return num2 + charge1
    case (num2 > 10):
    return num2 + charge2
    default:
      console.log('Please enter ONLY numbers')
  
  }

  }
console.log(addWithSurcharge(3, 14))
// -> 4, 16

console.log(addWithSurcharge('as', 2))
// -> Please enter ONLY numbers
```

Comment: You should first learn how to properly use a switch-case statement

Comment: Because `num2 <= 10` returns true, so that case is followed. You need a series of `if`s or at least two `switch`es. Or validate the parameters first.

Comment: @Frighi What do you mean? The syntax is correct and the pattern is very common.

Comment: A function can't return multiple values but it can, e.g. return an array, an object or a string. What is your expected result?

Comment: @jabaa is seriously common use `switch(true)` and do something else in cases? I don't think this is a properly use for a switch

Comment: @Frighi Yes, it's common in widely-used libraries and I don't know any reason to not use this pattern. It's usually more readable than a list of `if` / `else if` / `else` conditions.

Comment: @jabaa Thank you for explaining. The ultimate aim is `totSum = (num1 + charge*) + (num2 + charge*)` but before than that I am going to read all the positive and constructive comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch breaks after you return, so as soon as you condition is met, your result is returned. This is why you don't get the result you expected.

So basically you need two switches(if you stick to using switch/case) for each argument. And arguments validation in order to return 'Please enter ONLY numbers'.

But IMO, switch is much of overburden here, and can be replaced with just `if` statements, or even just ternary operators:

```js
const addWithSurcharge = (num1, num2) => {
   const charge1 = 1
   const charge2 = 2
   if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
      return 'Please enter ONLY numbers'
   }

   return {
      num1: num1 += num1 <= 10 ? charge1 : charge2,
      num2: num2 += num2 <= 10 ? charge1 : charge2    
   }
}

console.log(addWithSurcharge(3, 14))
// -> 4, 16

console.log(addWithSurcharge('as', 2))
// -> Please enter ONLY numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check their values one by one like below:

```
if(num1<=10)
 num1 = num1+charge1;
else
 num1 = num1+charge2;

if(num2<=10)
```

num2=      num2+charge1;
else
num2= num2+charge2;

there is no way to return two different variables in a function. you need to put them in another variable like below:

```
var res = {
  num1 : num1,
  num2 : num2
};
return res;
```

```js
function addWithSurcharge(num1, num2) {
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    return "please enter only numbers";
  }
  const charge1 = 1;
  const charge2 = 2;

  if (num1 <= 10)
   num1= num1 + charge1;
  else
   num1= num1 + charge2;

  if (num2 <= 10)
   num2= num2 + charge1;
  else
   num2= num2 + charge2;

  var res = {
    num1: num1,
    num2: num2
  };
  return res;
}
console.log(addWithSurcharge(3, 14))
// -> 4, 16

console.log(addWithSurcharge('as', 2))
// -> Please enter ONLY numbers
```

Comment: yea, using cases is unneeded fr

Comment: It returns `{
  "num1": 3,
  "num2": 14
}` istead of expected result

Comment: It is impossible to return expected result if the function doesn't return string. He can use this to return expected result : `return num1+ ' , '+num2;` instead of  `return res;`